# rsync files from subfolders on source to root of a folder on destination

Tags: file, include, rsync

I wish to sync a bunch of flac files that reside in various subfolders to the root of a folder on a destination.

An example of the directory structure on the source is:

```
source> tree Music/
Music/
├── R
│   ├── Radiohead
│   │   └── OK Computer
│   │       ├── 01 - Radiohead - Airbag.flac
│   │       ├── 02 - Radiohead - Paranoid Android.flac
│   └── Red Hot Chilli Peppers
│       └── Greatest Hits
│           ├── 01 - Red Hot Chili Peppers - Under the Bridge.flac
│           ├── 02 - Red Hot Chili Peppers - Give It Away.flac
```

I am using this command which syncs fine but includes the directory paths on the destination:

```
rsync -rltDzvh --delete -e ssh Music/ user@192.168.1.1:/Destination/ --include="*/" --include="*.flac" --exclude="*"
```

So on the destination the structure is:

```
destination> tree /Destination/
/Destination/
├── R
│   ├── Radiohead
│   │   └── OK Computer
│   │       ├── 01 - Radiohead - Airbag.flac
│   │       ├── 02 - Radiohead - Paranoid Android.flac
│   └── Red Hot Chilli Peppers
│       └── Greatest Hits
│           ├── 01 - Red Hot Chili Peppers - Under the Bridge.flac
│           ├── 02 - Red Hot Chili Peppers - Give It Away.flac
```

I want to prune all directories so only the files are placed into the root of /Destination/ e.g.

```
destination> tree /Destination/
/Destination/
├── 01 - Radiohead - Airbag.flac
├── 02 - Radiohead - Paranoid Android.flac
├── 01 - Red Hot Chili Peppers - Under the Bridge.flac
├── 02 - Red Hot Chili Peppers - Give It Away.flac
```

All the files have different names so that's ok and I have reviewed the various options in rsync such as --no-relative but have been unable to get it working as desired.

I also came up with:

```
find ./Music/ -name "*.flac" -exec rsync -ltDzvh {} -e ssh user@192.168.1.1:/Destination/ \;
```

But this means using ssh keys and is probably inefficient and if I want to use the --delete it would likely break everything.

So how would I achieve this whilst still being able to use --delete or --delete-excluded for times when I add, remove or rename items on my Music library on the source and have those changes sync to the destination?

Comment: What happens if you have files `src/Foo/Blubber/01 - Intro` and `src/Foo/Knorkator/01 - Intro` -- one will overwrite the other unless you take some steps to uniquely identify one or the other...

Comment: @sarnold, I did mention that in the question but to clarify...  When I rip CD's each file name includes the artist and song so I shouldn't have any duplicates file names.

Comment: Ah, so you did. Good. Sorry to miss it.